i want to know why my controller give nested response
In Spirngboot, I have use JpaRepository when i get any of the record from one table its associated with another table record, in this case i got recursive data.
example i have two tables(jobs and company), jobs have company field at entity, company have jobs field Set at company entity.
this is sample of my response

Here my Jobs entity
@Entity
public class Jobs {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String title;
    
    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company")
    private Company company;
..,

Company entity

@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
    
    @Column(length = 1500)
    private String about; 

    @Column( length = 600)
    private String companyLogoLink;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Jobs> jobs;
..,

I have already tried out Lazy loader at annotation
I expect when i save any new jobs record. its return job and associated company record not jobs record which is associated with company.
like
job{
   id:
   title:
   company: { 
       id:
       company_name:
       jobs: {
              avoid here repeated;
             }


When you fetch lazily, data is retrieved from the db on demand, when the getter is invoked.
Jackson uses getters/setters by default for serialization/deserialization. When it invokes the getter, jpa retrieves the data, then it invokes the getter on the new data when serializing it, jpa retrieves more data, and so on. I am surprised you are not getting stackoverflow error here, json format cannot represent the circular references between objects, which are absolutely legal in java.
Solutions:

Use the good practices - for de/serialization use DTOs (data transfer objects), not entities (which is the bad practice).
@JsonIgnore on the properties you don't need.
@JsonIdentityInfo and other jackson annotations, which can deal with circular references.


Instead of JsonIgnore I would use the dedicated pair of annotations: JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference.

I believe you're looking response like below so you have to do 2 changes in your both Pojo classes

Replace your company variable with below peace of code in Jobs Pojo
@JoinColumn(name = "company")
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable=false)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
private Company company;


Remove below code from Company Pojo
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
private Set<Jobs> jobs;



[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Job 1",
        "company": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "name 1",
            "about": "About 1",
            "companyLogoLink": "link 1",
            "jobs": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "Job 2",
                    "company": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "Job 1",
                    "company": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]


But I need that Set too in Company entity when I retrieve company object that associated jobs also I want.
